# Proper coloring of a tree

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, solution-verification, markov-chains, coloring

I don't understand this exercise (from Markov chains & Mixing times by David & Yuval) .

> EXERCISE 1.5. Let $T$ be a tree . Show that the graph whose vertices are proper 3-colorings of $T$ and whose edges are pairs of coloring which differ at only a single vertex is connected .

From "the graph whose vertices are proper 3-colorings of $T$" , I could only think that the graph is just $T=(V,E)$ such that
$\{u,v\} \in E \implies c(u) \neq c(v)  $ , where $c:V\to \{1,2,3\}$ is a
[proper coloring](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Proper_Coloring) , by definition of a [tree](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Tree_(Graph_Theory)) the graph is connected .

Although I also don't understand the rest of the exercise ...

Comment: What the exercise is really asking you to do is this: show that you can go from any proper 3-colouring $c_0$ to any other proper 3-colouring $c_n$ by a sequence of proper colourings $c_0, c_1, \dots, c_n$ --- where two consecutive colourings $c_i$ and $c_{i+1}$ only differ on a single vertex. Or put in words: you can get from one colouring to another by just changing the colour of 1 vertex at a time, in such a way that every in-between step is a proper colouring.